# Why am I not able to try and edit the code snippet without having to click on "Answer this Question"?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

If there is a code snippet in a question, I may want to edit and try how it's working without clicking on "Answer this Question". Personally, I am one of the type of person who reads through questions to get more context and application knowledge, not just to answer them. If there were a feature to edit the code snippet and try it out on my own it would have be helpful.

Comment: Some folks have kindly offered workarounds below, but I'll second the need for this: Sometimes I don't want to get myself in a state where I'm 1 click away from editing the OP question, or posting a new answer.  I just want to fiddle around with the OP's code to understand the problem, without any buttons being armed for posting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what the use-case is, here.

As far as I can think, either,

**You know the answer,** in which case, yeah, definitely test away, but you might as well write your draft in the answer box, since you know it'll work anyway.

or,

**You *don't* know the answer, but have a good guess,** in which case you're either well on your way to writing a full-on answer, so you should use the answer box, or you aren't, in which case you'll probably need something more advanced for debugging than the code snippets window.

---

It seems like this feature would fulfill a very small segment of actual uses, at the cost of having to be maintained in entirety by the Stack Exchange team. And realistically, the best solution to this would be another text box that you can put a snippet into and test, which means the only difference would be the lack of an "Answer" label and submit functionality.

I definitely respect the goal of making sure you're right before posting an answer, but I don't think there's anything wrong with fiddling around in the answer box *before* posting it, if the answer box gives you all the tooling you need. If it doesn't, then you're asking for a much bigger feature, and one which should be highlighted in this or another request.

Comment: what if i don't wanna answer that question .I saw someone has implemented something similar of my interest and i just want to try that out with my own customization.just like when you get a plunker or fiddle and to understand how  the result is achieved you make your own changes .I don't know if this is popular a use case.

Comment: @DivyaMV So you'd be using this as a sandbox for testing other people's answers? I suppose I can see merit in that if it's for the purposes of improving site quality. If you're just looking for a place to play, that's not really the purpose of [se], so I don't think it's worth them implementing (and, more importantly, supporting and maintaining) such a system.

Comment: i haven't thought about testing other people's snippet.But yeah that too is good to have!what i wanted is a learning template for me.

Comment: @DivyaMV Yeah, that's what I figured you were looking for. I think that's admirable, again, but it's just not really the goal of Stack Exchange. These sites are here for the purpose of asking and answering questions, and there's a lot of (occasionally liberal) features that speak to that goal, but there are much better places to play with these languages, whose goals are doing just that. Again, I think it would be useful, I just don't think it's *right* for Stack Exchange. I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: yeah! Its making sense. then i wonder why do we have a snippet in place? a link to the so-called other much better places would have sufficed. wouldn't they ? when i get such links i used to try them ,learn from them and save it for future references.

Comment: @DivyaMV To the goal of asking and answering questions, it can often be very useful to run examples inline. That's what snippets let us do. I guess one way to think of them, although not totally accurate, is that snippets are used as a *teaching tool*, rather than a *learning tool* here. Obviously to be one they must be the other, but the idea is that an answerer uses them to convey the information to the asker, so they aren't really built for being "played around with." They're good for it in small amounts, as I said in my answer, but that's it.

Comment: As for why it's not all outsourced, other sites are known for not being very reliable, and Stack Exchange likes to be a single source of information, so when Stack Snippets can be used to convey information more effectively, they're good to have on the site locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can click "edit" in the question as you do when you want to edit your post. Then, under the snippet, you'll see "edit above snippet" (or you can copy the whole markdown).

But what's wrong with choosing to copy snippet to answer? It doesn't actually posts you answer and it is the faster way.

Comment: don't i have to cancel that answer when i am not indenting to post my trial code in the post, I think that's unnecessary

Comment: @Div as you wish. Unless you want, it won't be posted anyway... And did you read the first part of my answer?

Comment: yes ,its the same there too .i wish there was a separate link in which we can edit or save the snippets for future reference.